# How to add ng2-smart-table nested columns in Angular 6

Tags: ionic3, angular6, ng2-smart-table

How to get multiple sub-columns in single columns (nested) in ng2-smart-table Angular2.

I have currency column - in that column i want to add multiple sub-columns like INR, USD,

Answer (score 0):

Flattening the data is highly recommended.